Why doesn't subscriber node work?
I'm trying to follow the tutorials for working with ROS2 jazzy in Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS.
Background:
I tryed to create Subscriber node as my practice for Implementing custom interfaces chapter.
Issue:
colcon build was succedded.
The subscriber node could run, but it was unresponsive to publidshed msg.
What is my error?
My Source
#include <memory>

#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"
#include "more_interfaces/msg/address_book.hpp"

class AddressBookSubscriber : public rclcpp::Node
{
public:
  AddressBookSubscriber()
  : Node("address_book_subscriber")
  {
    auto topic_callback =
      [this](const more_interfaces::msg::AddressBook & msg) -> void {
        RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "I heard: '%s'", msg.phone_number.c_str());
      };
    address_book_subscription_ =
      this->create_subscription<more_interfaces::msg::AddressBook>("topic", 10, topic_callback);
  }

private:
  rclcpp::Subscription<more_interfaces::msg::AddressBook>::SharedPtr address_book_subscription_;
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
  rclcpp::spin(std::make_shared<AddressBookSubscriber>());
  rclcpp::shutdown();
  return 0;
}

CMake.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(more_interfaces)

find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(rosidl_default_generators REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)

set(msg_files
  "msg/AddressBook.msg"
)

rosidl_generate_interfaces(${PROJECT_NAME}
  ${msg_files}
)

ament_export_dependencies(rosidl_default_runtime)

add_executable(publish_address_book src/publish_address_book.cpp)
ament_target_dependencies(publish_address_book rclcpp)

add_executable(subscribe_address_book src/subscribe_address_book.cpp)
ament_target_dependencies(subscribe_address_book rclcpp)

install(TARGETS
        publish_address_book
        subscribe_address_book
        DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME})

rosidl_get_typesupport_target(cpp_typesupport_target
        ${PROJECT_NAME} rosidl_typesupport_cpp)

target_link_libraries(publish_address_book "${cpp_typesupport_target}")
target_link_libraries(subscribe_address_book "${cpp_typesupport_target}")

ament_package()


I ran ros2doctor, when publisher and subscriber node had running. Two warnings appeared.  UserWarning: Publisher without subscriber detected on /address_book.
UserWarning: Subscriber without publisher detected on /topic.
Why was subscriber waiting /topic instead of /address_book?

I noticed my mistake.
my error
    address_book_subscription_ =
      this->create_subscription<more_interfaces::msg::AddressBook>("topic", 10, topic_callback);

correct
    address_book_subscription_ =
      this->create_subscription<more_interfaces::msg::AddressBook>("address_book", 10, topic_callback);

